# Daw lines passing throught "cells" on canvas

Tags: android, grid, android-canvas

I need to figure out how to draw vertical and horizontal lines passing at the center of a cell.

By the way, I have a 2D grid with 100x100 cells how can I draw lines that pass inside those cells dividing each cell in 4 parts?

I use the bellow to draw:

```
//Draw grid lines horizontally and vertically
    for (int i = 0; i < gameBoard.length; i++) {
        if((i * cellWidth) + xOffset > 0 && (i * cellWidth) + xOffset < width) {
            canvas.drawLine((i * cellWidth) + xOffset, 0, (i * cellWidth) + xOffset, height, blackPaint);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < gameBoard[0].length; i++) {
        if((i * cellHeight) + yOffset > 0 && (i * cellHeight) + yOffset < height) {
            canvas.drawLine(0, (i * cellHeight) + yOffset, width, (i * cellHeight) + yOffset, blackPaint);
        }
    }
```

This draw something simillar to this (each cell have a GestureDetector)

[image]

Can't find a way to draw others lines passing this time inside each cell so that it divide it in four parts.

Something like this (red are cells):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//Draw grid lines horizontally and vertically
for (int i = 0; i < gameBoard.length; i++) {
    if((i * cellWidth) + xOffset > 0 && (i * cellWidth) + xOffset < width) {
        canvas.drawLine((i * cellWidth) + xOffset, 0, (i * cellWidth) + xOffset, height, blackPaint);
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < gameBoard[0].length; i++) {
    if((i * cellHeight) + yOffset > 0 && (i * cellHeight) + yOffset < height) {
        canvas.drawLine(0, (i * cellHeight) + yOffset, width, (i * cellHeight) + yOffset, blackPaint);
    }
}

xOffset += cellWidth * 0.5f;
yOffset += cellHeight * 0.5f;

//Draw grid lines horizontally and vertically AGAIN.. but now with offsets moved half size to the right/bottom
for (int i = 0; i < gameBoard.length; i++) {
    if((i * cellWidth) + xOffset > 0 && (i * cellWidth) + xOffset < width) {
        canvas.drawLine((i * cellWidth) + xOffset, 0, (i * cellWidth) + xOffset, height, blackPaint);
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < gameBoard[0].length; i++) {
    if((i * cellHeight) + yOffset > 0 && (i * cellHeight) + yOffset < height) {
        canvas.drawLine(0, (i * cellHeight) + yOffset, width, (i * cellHeight) + yOffset, blackPaint);
    }
}
```

As a side note, I would consider using functions instead of repeating code! Good luck ;)

Comment: Thanks, it works as expected. BUT the grid keeps moving upwards on every touch And also the scoll is completely broken. Any idea?

Comment: I mean, your code has broken everything. the gestureDetector doesn't behave as intended anymore

Comment: And why the Offsets are being multiplied by 0.5f ? This make the whole grid moving upwards then throws a NullPointerException when it reaches the edge

Comment: This code, should not break anything, because it's just drawing! But I can't help you if you don't show me your code.

Comment: @esQmo_ This code `xOffset += cellWidth * 0.5f` moves the horizontal offset half cell to the right.

Comment: NVM, I fixed it. I didnt immplement GestureDetector properly. Your code inspired me though. Now I can even draw on grid intersections